# Java : Count duplication in first and last letters of String array

Tags: java, arrays, string, char, ascii

I'm trying to count duplication in first and last letters of String array. I have 2 int array one for the first letters and another for last letters. I think I have to somehow join both of them to become int [] count, so I can pass on to displayCount. How do I join them? I know there is something I have to add something in the for loop, but I am not sure what to add. Right now it counts and gives me the wrong answer. Please help. Thank you.

```
public static int[] countChar(String[] str){
int[] begin= new int[26];
int[] end= new int[26];
for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++){
int x = str[0].charAt(0)-'a';
int y = str[0].charAt(str[0].length()-1)-'a';
begin[x]++;
end[y]++;
}
return begin; // I can return only one 
//value in a method how do I join begin and end together?
}
public static void displayCounts(int[] counts) {
    for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++) {
      System.out.println(counts[i] + " " + (char)(i + 'a'));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   String[] str = {"julie","eleven","eve"};

    // Count the occurrences of each letter
    int[] counts = countChar(str);

    // Display counts
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("The occurrences of each letter are:");
    displayCounts(counts);
  }
}
```

this is the answer it gives me.

```
The occurrences of each letter are:
0 a
0 b
0 c
0 d
0 e
0 f
0 g
0 h
0 i
3 j
0 k
0 l
0 m
0 n
0 o
0 p
0 q
0 r
0 s
0 t
0 u
0 v
0 w
0 x
0 y
0 z
```

Answer (score 0):

Create new class that contains both arrays and use and return this new class

```
class Results {

  int begin [26];
  int end [26];

}


Results countChar(String[] str){

 Results results = new Results ();
 .
 .
 .
 results.begin[x]++;
 return results ;

}
```

**edit**

By the way, I think you need to change to

```
int x = str[i].charAt(0)-'a';
int y = str[i].charAt(str[i].length()-1)-'a';
```

as you were only looking at the first String otherwise